# Eclipse e4 disable close in shared element

Tags: eclipse, e4

I created a part as shared element.
and it is used as placeholder with no closeable on the part stack.

But at launching the e4 application
I saw that close button on placeholder is enabled (like 'X').

Why doesn't the placeholder apply the closeable option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the stack renderer for determining the close flag is:

```java
protected boolean isClosable(MPart part) {
    // if it's a shared part check its current ref
    if (part.getCurSharedRef() != null) {
        return !(part.getCurSharedRef().getTags().contains(IPresentationEngine.NO_CLOSE));
    }

    return part.isCloseable();
}
```

And the JavaDoc for `IPresentationEngine.NO_CLOSE` (value `"NoClose") says:

> When applied as a tag to an MPlaceholder inhibits the display of the
>   close affordance. This allows a part to be closeable in one
>   perspective but not in a different one

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I've added tags value "NoClose"into PlaceHolder.
My problem was cleared by your solution.